# Problem overwritting java method from clojure

Tags: clojure, interop

I am desperetly trying to create a class that with a "toString" method from clojure
According to clojure docs the following should work:

```
(ns override-test.simpleClass
   (:gen-class
     :name         simpleClass
     :methods      [[^{Override {}}  toString [] String]]
     :state        state
     :init         init
     :constructors {[String] []}))
(defn -init
  [name_]
  [[] (atom name_)])
(defn -toString [this]
  (deref (.state this)))
```

However evaluating  
`(simpleClass. "test")` 
Throws
`CompilerException java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name "toString" with signature "()Ljava.lang.String;" in class file simpleClass, compiling:(override_test/simpleClass.clj:19:3)`
Any incites of what i might be doing wrong ?

Comment: Not an answer because I don't know and haven't tried it, but, Why did you include `toString` in `:methods`?  [The manual](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/gen-class) describes `:methods` as not including inherited methods: "The generated class automatically defines all of the non-private methods of its superclasses/interfaces. This parameter can be used
to specify the signatures of additional methods of the generated class."

Comment: I just didn't think of toString  to be an inherited method at the moment. I didn't subclass from anything explicitly   so it didn't occur me. But i tested it as soon as i realized it from you comment, and it turns that this was the problem. Also the ^{Overide {}} metadata probably added to my confusion because i was thinking that it was somehow necessary. You have been most helpfull

Answer (score 1):

As Biped Phill mentioned the problem was that toString seems to be already implemented by virtue of the automatic subclassing mechanism of gen-class. Probably Ljava.lang. String is treated as a (?) superclass and toString is added automatically, so i just had to remove it from :methods which is for not inherited methods and it worked like a charm.

Comment: The superclass is `Object`.